# .Net 3.5: Piece of Code I Don't Understand, Possibly Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I am working on a project at the office, at the moment, that is written in VB, using the .Net 3.5 Framework (which may not be relevant). I have stumbled across a bit of code that I have not seen and - after some Googling - cannot find much about (predominantly because I do not know what else to Google).

```
'Here's the code:
Dim Identifier(32)() As Object
```

What I am unfamiliar with is the `()()` piece of the code. Is this a mult-dimensional array? If not, what is it (so I can go an do some more reading)?

Comment: It's called [jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkhhsz9t(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå so, really it needs to be written (or, it is best practice to write): `Dim Identifier()() As Object = New Object(32)() {}`?

Comment: Actually, I preferred the .net way: `Dim <variable> As <type>`: `Dim Identifier As Object()() = New Object(32)() {}`.